# RegExp works in perl, javascript and objective-c but not in java

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I'm converting code from Javascript to Java and I found a regular expression that in Java  doesn't work as expected (using the standard class [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)).

It works fine in perl, js and also in Cocoa with NSRegularExpression

The reg exp is `([a-z]*) ([0-9]*)` and the java code is shown below

It must match two groups separated by a space, the first group contains only letters, the second group only numbers

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("([a-z]*) ([0-9]*)").matcher("hello 101");
while (matcher.find()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println(i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

}

The numeric group is never returned.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You end your `for` loop too early:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
//                ^^   
    System.out.println(i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
}
```

With two capturing groups, `.groupCount()` is 2:

- `.group(0)` is the entire match
- `.group(1)` contains the text matched by the first capturing group
- `.group(2)` contains the text matched by the second capturing group

If you stop `i` at 1, you never get to the second group.

Comment: Oh my god!! I never realized groupCount returns 2, I expected (wrongly) 3!! Thank you very much